# Query - multiple criteria with dates - Not expected output

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have this query function:

```
=query('Database'!A1:AD979,"select* where (F < date """&text(today(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&""") or (J <  date """&text(today(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&""") or (U = 'Terminated')")
```

From my understanding, this function should select any row that matches at least one of the criteria in the query. Yet, the result of this query also shows rows that do not meet any of these criteria.

Do you have any idea / explanations?

Thks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=query('DataBase'!A1:AD979, "select* where F < date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' or J <  date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' or U = 'Terminated'", 0)
```

Note: it may be possible to exclude also rows with empty cells in F and J?
In that case, try

```
=query('DataBase'!A1:AD979, "select* where (F < date '"&text(today(), "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' AND F is not null) or (J <  date '"&text(today(), "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and J is not null) or U = 'Terminated'", 0)
```

Comment: This query function has the same result as the original one I posted. The issue is that there are quite a lot of empty rows, mainly in columns F and J that are dates. I assume the query counts it as 0 therefore a value that is inferior to today's date. Then, it pulls the data of these rows as well. The question is how to tell the query: Take F or J if they are dates and not blank or 0. So far I have not managed to make it work